# Two clicks in html/jQuery registered

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, laravel

I printed several times HTML-part code with different ids (`${element.id}` in every part they are different). Now first child element works correctly, but others register two clicks(after one click its fade-in and fade-out). I want to remove this error. Im using Laravel as main framework. Sorry for my English:)
Thank in advance!

```
<div class="notification warning closeable" id="checkbox-area">
<input type="checkbox" name="blocks[]" class="form-check-input" id="element${element.id}" value="${element.url}" checked>
<label class="form-check-label" for="element${element.id}">${element.name}
<img src="${window.location.origin}/${element.thumbnail}" id="original" class="imgBlocks">

</label>
<button class="dropbtn" data-id="${element.id}" type="button">...</button>
</div>
<div class="drop-down" id="drop_${element.id}">
<div id="text-generation" class="drop-down-text">
</div>
<button type="button" id="btn-text-updater">new text</button>
</div>
```

```
const textGen = document.getElementById('text-generation');
        const btnUpdateTextGen = document.getElementById('btn-text-updater');
        let countTextRefresh = 0;

$(dotsBtn).click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let id = $(this).attr("data-id")

    if ( $("#drop_"+id).is(":visible") ) {
        $("#drop_"+id).fadeOut(1000);
    } else {
        $("#drop_"+id).fadeIn(1000);
    }

})
```

Comment: Can you please put a more complete code? It seems something other causing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change:

```
    if ( $("#drop_"+id).is(":visible") ) {
        $("#drop_"+id).fadeOut(1000);
    } else {
        $("#drop_"+id).fadeIn(1000);
    }
```

to

```
    if ( $("#drop_"+id).is(":visible") ) {
        $("#drop_"+id).fadeOut(1000);
        return;
    }
        $("#drop_"+id).fadeIn(1000);
```

Comment: The same thing. Nothing changed